# PowerQuery - Transform Certain values but not all

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I am trying to consolidate some fee data, I dump all csv's into a folder and use a simple get data function to consolidate. The issue I am having is that only one file in the batch (30) uses commas instead of decimals for a unit price i.e. 1,88 instead of 1.88 which causes the error.

It isn't the same value every time so I can't replace value. I can't use a mass change either as some commas are required i.e. 1,000.00

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

I tried replacing values but as mentioned the value changes.
Tried bulk update to decimal numbers but it just omitted the comma altogether which resulted in the values just being incorrect.
Tried find and replace, but as mentioned it replaced necessary commas for '000s

Comment: if there are decimals for separator  1.880, why would there ever be commas in the same file like 1,000 ? Is the final name constant that has the issue?

Comment: it's a combination of multiple files from different regions, European entities using that format is causing the issue.

Comment: You will need to find something about the file that allows you to tell which country it is coming from. Then you can apply the appropriate culture to the transformation function. With the limited information you provide, I could not even guess at what this might be.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the numbers to 2 decimal places within the same set columns?

If so, replace all `,` and `.` with nothing. Convert to number, divide by 100. You do not need commas in PowerQuery, you add those in later in either the data model or in the spreadsheet.

Alternatively, is there anything in that one file that can help you identify it's culture? If so you can use "culture" option when transforming types, which PQ will handle the rest.

Comment: I don't think your first option is particularly robust. How would you know, for example, given `1,888` if this represents `one thousand eight hundred and eighty-eight` or `one and 888/thousandths`

Comment: I was meaning that if each column had consistent number of DP then this crude approach would work.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the position of the comma and decimal.  If the position of the decimal is greater then the comma than it is a comma decimal. Then Number.From or change column types with the right culture setting. (e.g. Number.From(_, "da-DK") )

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], 
    culture_pos = List.PositionOf(
        Source[Column1], 
        {",","."}, 
        Occurrence.First, 
        (x,y) => List.ContainsAll(Text.ToList(x),y)
        ),
    culture = if culture_pos >= 0 
        then if Text.PositionOf(Source[Column1]{culture_pos}, ".") > Text.PositionOf(Source[Column1]{culture_pos}, ",") then "en-US" else "da-DK"
        else "en-US",
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type number}}, culture)
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

If you are doing a Get Data --> From Folder put this step into your Transform Sample File.